# Meteor/Autoform-maps/Google-maps package error?

Tags: google-maps, meteor, meteor-autoform

I am using both the yogiben:autoform-map and the dburles:google-maps packages in my application. It seems that they dont work well together. The code that uses dburles:google-maps works fine, but the autoform map is throwing this error:

```
Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at t.afMap.rendered (d56467d85b9f586916cc49f2dba3c180bfed1ddc.js:210)
at p (d56467d85b9f586916cc49f2dba3c180bfed1ddc.js:154)
at a (d56467d85b9f586916cc49f2dba3c180bfed1ddc.js:154)
at d56467d85b9f586916cc49f2dba3c180bfed1ddc.js:66
at Function.e._withTemplateInstanceFunc (d56467d85b9f586916cc49f2dba3c180bfed1ddc.js:66)
at n (d56467d85b9f586916cc49f2dba3c180bfed1ddc.js:66)
at null.<anonymous> (d56467d85b9f586916cc49f2dba3c180bfed1ddc.js:66)
at d56467d85b9f586916cc49f2dba3c180bfed1ddc.js:65
at Object.c._withCurrentView (d56467d85b9f586916cc49f2dba3c180bfed1ddc.js:65)
at d56467d85b9f586916cc49f2dba3c180bfed1ddc.js:65
```

My html:

```
    {{#autoForm class="add" id="add" collection="ServiceProviders" type="insert"}} 
    {{> afQuickField name="businessname"}} 
    {{> afQuickField name="officelocation"}}
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Create!</button>
    {{/autoForm}}
```

My collection:

```
officelocation: {
type: String,
label: 'Location of Office',
autoform: {
  type: 'map',
  afFieldInput: {
    type: 'map',
    geolocation: true,
    searchBox: true,
    autolocate: true
  }
} }
```

Also, this autoform was working perfectly fine till I added the dburles:google-maps package. It seems that "GoogleMaps" is not ready yet when this code is being called in autoform-map.coffee

```
    GoogleMaps.init { libraries: 'places' }, () =>
    mapOptions =
        zoom: 0
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId[@data.options.mapType]
        streetViewControl: false
```

This seems weird because I am already doing on meteor startup:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    if (GoogleMaps.loaded()?false:true) {
        GoogleMaps.load();
    }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict between these two packages as noted by yogiben here: https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-autoform-map/issues/9

Comment: Is there a recommended way around this? Or are we limited to using only 1 of the packages in the app for now?

Comment: So, currently probably there is no way to use both at same time as its an issue with mrt:googlemaps, I am going to be implementing my own g-map + searchbox feature (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)